# How to display the index of the largest value of array in C?

Tags: c

The user has to input 10 values and that you should display the largest value and its index. I already got the largest value using for loop..

```
largest = num[0];
for (n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
    if (largest < num[n])
        largest = num[n];
}
```

but I don't know how to get its index. I've tried googling it but they are in java (P.S. I'm only a beginner)

Comment: You mean....like...saving 'n'?

Comment: If you're already saving the largest value, it should be very trivial to also save the index. Think about it a little :)

Comment: @janelleyace Do you need to keep enetered values or it is enough to output the largest value and its number in the entered sequence?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of storing the largest value, just store the index:

```
size_t index_of_max = 0;
for(size_t n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
  if(numbers[index_of_max] < numbers[n]) {
    index_of_max = n;
  }
}
```

Also, just a small stylistic note: always use braces for `if`s, even if they're one statement. It's good practice that can avoid bugs (and not doing it has been the cause of a lot of security problems).

Comment: Minor: Perhaps `size_t` rather than `int`?

Comment: @chux: Been a while since I actually wrote C. Is that best practice for indexes?

Comment: IMO- Yes.  `size_t` is an unsigned integer type wide enough to represent any valid array index.  `INT_MAX` may be less.  An issue with large arrays though and not ones of 10 values like here.

Comment: @chux: Updated. Does `size_t` alias to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`? I guess you *could* have a 64-bit platform with 32-bit `int`s and a `char` array that couldn't be indexed by a 32-bit uint... :-P

Comment: `size_t` may be the same size as `unsigned` or `unsigned long` or something else.  It is at least 16 bit.  Never came across a system where is is narrower than `unsigned`.

Comment: @janelleyace: My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Always index starts from 0. try this i hope this may help you out.

```
var max = arr[0];
var maxIndex = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (arr[i] > max) {
    maxIndex = i;
    max = arr[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: `arr.length` in `C`?  What is  `var`??